# VBA: Conditional formatting cells below a text

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a raw data containing data in Table format. where I need to highlight the consecutive 6 rows if any cell value contains text "Urgent" which can appear any where in cell.

I had written a code, but didn't work out for me. here I am hard-coding with "J"column. However my String can appear in any column.

```
    With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Urgent*"",$J1))"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 7405514
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
```

![excel]https://ibb.co/swkBbtY

Comment: Just be aware that `Conditional Formatting` is volatile. When you say your string can appear anywhere? What exactly do you mean? Literally anywhere, or just first row? It would really matter because a volatile function that recalculates on all cells in a spreadsheet will become way too sluggish.

Comment: i am populating Two table from Pivot table via Macro code having headers at 27th row and 40th Row in which "Urgent " can come anywhere from column "E:M"

Comment: is it possible to acquire the same via macro code. like find the column number of urgent and using offset we can color the 6 cells below. 

`Set rFind= .Cells(1, 1).Find("Urgent*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
.Range(.Cells(28,rFind.Column),.Cells(28+5,rFind.Column))..Interior.ColorIndex = 6
`